# Nonlinear optimization of a matrix with the costraint to be orthonormal

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, matlab, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

I'm trying to find the matrix x which minimize the following cost function :

$J =||B_b -x*B_n||^2$

with the constraint that x has to be an orthonormal matrix. 
I'm trying to use MATLAB fmincon tool, but I'm kind of stucked in how to pose the problem to the solver. What I did up until now is writing an objective function like this :

```
function f=objfun(x)

B_b = [8.53086963374351e-06,-1.56083520340848e-06,2.62167147268028e-05];
B_n = [-8.53086963374351e-06,1.56083520340848e-06,2.62167147268028e-05];

f = (norm(B_b' - x*B_n'))^2;     % Cost function
```

The costraints can be expressed as :

$det(x) = 1$

$trace(I-x'x) = 0 $

Where I is the identity matrix.
But I don't get how to write them for MATLAB's fmincon.

Can someone help me to realize what I'm doing wrong in posing the problem to MATLAB and how I can express the costraint to solve this costrained problem ?

Comment: fmincon works on vectors, so have your function transform the vector to a matrix (reshape) as the first step in evaluating the function values

Comment: You can add the constraint into cost function instead of using a solver that can handle constraints. Just add norm(x'*x-I)^2 or something like it.

Comment: @LinAlg if fmincon works on vectors, why I have to reshape the vector into a matrix ?

Comment: @mathreadler you mean to add 

norm(x'*x-eye(3))^2 == 0;
det(x) == 1;

before defining f ?

Comment: No binary comparisons. Just +norm(x'$*$x-eye(3))^2 . It will behave better with any calculus based solver and probably other solvers also. Maybe you need 1e3$*$ in front of also.